# C# ListBox.DrawMode disappeared

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, listbox-control

Probably a simple question, but still a mystery:

Error: 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'DrawMode' ...

How is this possible? Yesterday I tinkered with DrawMode and made a great listbox. Now in the same Visual Studio 2008 environment, but different project, this error. ListBox.SelectedItem etc is available, why not .DrawMode ??? I do have 'using System.Windows.Forms;' in my source.

---

OK This is what I found in the [microsoft manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms229679%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

The .NET Compact Framework does not support the DrawMode, DrawItem, and other drawing members for list box and other controls, but you can program that functionality.

I am back into programming.

Comment: Make sure both projects reference the same version of the .NET Framework.

Comment: @Nuffin AFAIK that propery has been there since v1 of the .NET Framework

Comment: I will go through the settings in VS now

Comment: chk System.Windows.Forms dll in there

Comment: I am replacing a custom control SmallListBox by a regular ListBox, and in VS/Tools/Settings/Windows Forms Designer/Data UI Customization there is a checkmark next to ListBox as an "associated control" to "data type string". Could this cause trouble? I don't want to break code in other forms referring to the custom control, so should/can I remove this checkmark? (scary stuff)

Comment: I am using the `.Net Compact Framework` for a Windows Mobile device. This version does not show up in the [online microsoft doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)  under "different versions"

Comment: .Net Compact Framework does not support "DrawMode"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably created the wrong kind of project.

For example, [System.Windows.Controls.ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox_properties%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) doesn't contain a DrawMode property.

Comment: OK. Confusing. But the error message referred to the right namespace: System.Windows.Forms.ListBox does not contain a def for DrawMode ???

Comment: Now things are getting worse. The designer does not show, the error is that some base classes cannot be loaded. Strange, but the code view can load those. In the Using declaration, System.Windows.Forms has turned grey with 'hint' that this is a redundant declaration. When I type `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox l;` I get nice help from intellisense, but the text appears grey. So it is there, and it is not there.

Comment: Sounds messed up... Have you tried: (1) Close Visual Studio, (2) Delete the project's bin and obj folder and any .suo file, (3) reopen and try compiling again.

Comment: I did, and also the .ncb file, apparently the IntelliSense database, was pretty big: 18MB, now 11KB. Did not fix my problem though. There was a msg about a base class could not be loaded, I wanted to open it using right-mouse click on "goto definition", but hit "open designer". But the designer opened and I can work again. Magic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You probably confused `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox` from windows forms with the one from asp.net webforms `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox` or the one of WPF `System.Windows.Controls.ListBox` (which both do not have that property).